# Set width based on HTML text

Tags: jquery, css

How to set width to `.layer-info` based on value within `.score-java`? Decimal number should be integer = 9.8 will be 98%, 9 will be 90% etc. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-info">Result</div>
</div>
<span class="score-java">9.8</span>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
/*review score*/
$(".score-java").text();
$(".score-java").siblings(".layer").children();
```

Codepen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdXNLJ?editors=1010

edit:
What is the solution for multiple .layer on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat()` to parse the score:

```
var score = $(".score-java").text();
$(".layer-info").css('width', parseFloat(score) * 10 + '%');
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOegYm?editors=1010

Comment: How to make it work for multiple elements?


<div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-info">Result</div>
</div>
<span class="score-java">5.8</span>

<div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-info">Result</div>
</div>
<span class="score-java">3.8</span>

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the text value of the `.score-java` element then multiply it by 10 to get the percentage value of the width and apply that to the sibling `.layer`. Try this:

```
var width = parseFloat($(".score-java").text() || 0) * 10;
$(".score-java").prev(".layer").find('.layer-info').width(width + '%');
```

[**Working example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pygRJX?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Save the text from the element `.score-java` into a variable:

```
var value = $(".score-java").text();
```

And assign it as css to the element `.layer-info`:

```
$(".layer-info").css("width", value*10 + "%");
```